# get rid of background color in a translucent circle css div while dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a circular div, that gets dragged for drag and drop operation. When I drag this div, there is a translucent square around the circular div.

**How do I get rid of that?**

```
body{
    background : #BBD1DF;
}
.dragdemo {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    color: #efe;
}
.bgcolor{
    background : transparent;
}

#coverup {
    background: white;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}



<div class="bgcolor">
    <div id="drag-coveredup" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting another gif around the circular div and making that transparent, but it didn't work.

Here's the jsfiddle link - 
http://jsfiddle.net/j6YuX/1/

Comment: Try `outline:none`. PS. your fiddle is not working for me in any browser. Try using JQuery draggable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
overflow:hidden
```

got the work done!

Comment: can you explain / provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
Give a look to this fiddle, may be it can help you, http://jsfiddle.net/Fyd48/10/
```

But in my opinion, it won't be possible.